# intel xdk really slow, including the demo

Tags: intel-xdk

I've been creating a game for the last few weeks and everything seemed to be fine on the emulator. But when I tried testing and building it for my Android device (Sony Xperia Z), it was very slow. I tried one of the demo applications they gave with the XDK (Rolling Can) and this one was very slow as well.

I'm wandering if everything I did was for nothing, or that there is a reason for this problem. Can someone help?

Answer (score 2):

The emulator in the Intel XDK is an implementation of the Ripple Cordova emulator. It is running in a desktop browser that is based on the Chromium project. Thus, it has substantially more resources (especially CPU and RAM) to draw upon than your phone or tablet does.

Likewise, your HTML5 app runs inside what is commonly referred to as a "webview," which is kind of like an embedded browser. Some features in this webview are disabled by the OEM firmware, it varies, there is no hard rules.

To address the wide variance in webview performance and HTML5 features that you find on Android devices The XDK also provides a build option based on the Crosswalk open source project. When you build your app using the Crosswalk build option you'll get consistent features and, generally, much better performance on your Android device. (This is only available for Android 4.x devices.) This comes at the cost of adding about 15MB to your application size, because a complete embedded browser is included with the application.

Give the Crosswalk build a try and see if that provides the results you need.

---

As of February, 2017, the Crosswalk Project [has been retired](https://crosswalk-project.org/blog/crosswalk-final-release.html). Crosswalk 23 was the last version of the Crosswalk library produced by the Crosswalk team. You can continue to build for the Crosswalk library using Cordova CLI or PhoneGap Build, but no further updates to the Crosswalk library will occur beyond version 23 (FYI: the Crosswalk 23 library for Android is based on the Chromium 53 runtime release).

If you are only distributing your mobile apps on Android 5 and greater there is no compelling reason for including Crosswalk as part of your app. The Android 5+ webviews are regularly updated, via the Android store, to include an up-to-date copy of the Chrome webview, providing good performance and current features.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However I'm using C++ now. I didn't expect a solution any more. I hope it will be useful for people with the same problem.

Comment: i was looking for reason why my intel app preview is so slow. the answer was size of project. thanks

Comment: Crosswalk will no longer updated starting february 2017 T_T)

Comment: @Kokizzu - thank you for the prompt, I've updated my answer to let people know the alternatives.